# $f$ is continuous and differentiable then intermediate value theorem is true about $f'(x)$ beside not definitely being continous.

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Prove if $f$ is continuous and differentiable over $(c,d)$ then for $a,b\in(c,d)$ for every $\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is between between $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$, there is an $\alpha\in(a,b)$ where $f'(\alpha)=\lambda$.

Comment: Huh??? I can't parse the title.

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)

Answer (score 1):

Since $f: (c,d) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and differentiable, then
so the restriction of $f$ to the compact [a,b] is also. 
Using notation abuse, I will also denote this restriction by $f$. Let $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x)=f(x)-\lambda x$. Then $g'(x)=f'(x)-\lambda$. 
By the Weierstrass Theorem, g has minimum in $[a,b]$. Let $\alpha \in [a,b]$ such that $g(\alpha)\le g(x)$, for all $x \in [a,b]$. By hipothesis, $g'(a)<0$ and $g'(b)>0$. However $g'(\alpha)=0 \implies \alpha \in (a,b)$ and $f'(\alpha)= \lambda$.

Comment: How can you conclude there's a minimum if it's not continuous?

Comment: $g$ is continuous because $f$ is continuous. Note that $g(x)=f(x)-\lambda x$